# How to configure Deployment Synchronizer for API Manager cluster products

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have configured API Manager cluster environment, and seperated product into GatewayManager, GatewayWorker, KeyManager, APIPublisher and APIStore. Now I want to configure SVN-based deployment sychronizer, but according to the document https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/SVN-based+Deployment+Synchronizer, it seems only manager and worker nodes can be configured with svn synchronizer, how does configure it for KeyManager, APIPublisher and APIStore?
Below is my ELB loadbalancer.conf:

```
apimanager {
    domains   {
        abc.wso2am.domain {
            tenant_range    *;
            group_mgt_port 4560;
            mgt {
                hosts   mgt.wso2am.abc.com;
            }
            worker {
                hosts   wso2am.abc.com;
            }
        }
        abc.wso2am.key.domain {
            tenant_range    *;
            group_mgt_port 4580;
            key {
                hosts   key.wso2am.abc.com;
            }
        }

        abc.api.pub-store.domain {
            tenant_range    *;
            group_mgt_port 4590;
            publisher {
                hosts   api-publisher.abc.com;
            }
            store {
                hosts   api-store.abc.com;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The svn configuration of GatewayManager,KeyManager,API Publisher and API store in carbon.xml is as below:

```
<DeploymentSynchronizer>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <AutoCommit>true</AutoCommit>
    <AutoCheckout>true</AutoCheckout>
    <RepositoryType>svn</RepositoryType>
    <SvnUrl>svn://wso2svnrep:6001/depsync_am/</SvnUrl>
    <SvnUser>test</SvnUser>
    <SvnPassword>test</SvnPassword>
    <SvnUrlAppendTenantId>true</SvnUrlAppendTenantId>
</DeploymentSynchronizer>
```

When I set svn config in API Publisher, it occurred error as following when startup:

```
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-03-10 06:56:50,609] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext} -  StandardWrapper.Throwable {org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext}
```

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tokEP': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authzEndpointBean' while setting bean property 'serviceBeans' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authzEndpointBean' defined in URL [jndi:/localhost/oauth2/WEB-INF/cxf-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/identity/oauth/cache/AuthorizationGrantCacheKey
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure depsync for gateways, since API artifacts are deployed in gateways. If you configure secondary userstore, you need depsync for KM too.(That is, you need to have manager/worker) Else, you can copy the user-mgt.xml of the secondary usertsore, in all nodes.

Comment: Do you mean that it's no need to configure depsync for API Publisher and API Store?